# Balancing Equation - 30 seconds on 30% of textbook pages, 10 seconds on 70% of pages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to figure out a logic problem and am getting stuck with how to set up the equation -

If a student takes 40 minutes to read a section of a textbook, having spent 30% of her time reading pages that took her 30 seconds to read, and the other 70% of her time skimming pages that took her 10 seconds each to read, how many pages did she read?

I tried 40 = .30(30x) + .7(10x) where x is the number pages read, but I'm off by a lot, I think.

Comment: Be very precise when you define your variables. You wrote $x$ is the number of pages read, but there are two separate sections of pages read: first the student reads some pages, then she skims some more pages. It's not the same number of pages each time, so you can't use $x$ for both.

Comment: @Y.Forman that makes sense - but I can't figure out how to set it up in terms of one variable. For example, I think the 10 second pages should be (some larger sum - x) where x represents the number of 30 second pages but I'm not sure what that larger sum is?

Comment: Are you comfortable using multiple equations with multiple variables? Sometimes that's easier.

Comment: In fact that larger sum is the total number of pages in the section, which is exactly what you're looking for in the end, so you don't know it yet.

Comment: @Y.Forman I see what you're saying and I think I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you don’t mix units: minutes and seconds are not equivalent. If she spent 40 minutes, that’s 2400 seconds. 30 percent of that total time is is 720 seconds spent at 30 seconds per page, leaving 1680 seconds spent at 10 seconds per page.

Does that help?

Comment: that's really helpful thank you! I think I was just forgetting about the conversion before and then it's much easier to see it in terms of %s of seconds of the total # of seconds.

Comment: You may express your gratitude by up-voting the answer and setting it as the default answer for this page.